# Providing both an async protocol and a completion block based protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have a framework that has a delegate protocol `Foo` which the developer needs to conform to on init:

```
public protocol Foo {
  func render(completion: (Bool) -> Void)
}
```

However, I want to provide them the option of implementing an async version of this protocol:

```
public extension Foo {
  func render() async -> Bool
}
```

The delegate would be set like this:

```
MyFramework.init(delegate: self)
```

They can then implement EITHER the async or the completion block version of the function. There would be more of these sorts of functions. They need to implement one and only one of each type. Is this possible? I can't make them both optional because one is required.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure I understand, I just want them to be able to implement one or the other. Are you saying all the delegate funcs should be optional?

Comment: Yes. You can't specify through the protocol itself that they implement only one of the functions. They both need to be optional and then you can document which one you will call in preference. You could also perform a check in your `init` and throw an exception if both are implemented. In reality you are probably making things too complicated for yourself. If your framework has a minimum target that supports Async then just implement the Async. If your framework supports swift versions without Async then just use the completion handler.