# Identical function names choosing incorrect version

Tags: ios, swift

I have two functions with identical names. One has a completion block, another returns a value. Both have optional parameters:

```
static func foo(
  bar: String,
  one: [String: Any]? = nil,
  two: MyType? = nil,
  three: ((State) -> Void)? = nil
) {}

static func foo(
  bar: String,
  one: [String: Any]? = nil,
  two: MyType? = nil
) -> State {}
```

When I call this:

```
foo(bar: "value")
```

it defaults to the second function above, rather than the first. Ideally it should only do that if I am storing the return value like this:

```
let x = foo(bar: "value")
```

Why is this not the case?

Comment: Well, the `State`-returning overload gets chosen because it has a fewer parameters. that are not passed in. Can't tell you where this is documented though (it's probably not) - you'd have to look into Swift's source code. I can probably post a more helpful answer if you change your question to "how can I get it to call the void-returning overload", unless you know how to do that already.

Comment: Putting [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819) here in case "why isn't overload resolution based on whether I have `let x =` at the front implemented in Swift" is what you are actually asking.

Comment: Agreed with Sweeper that ambiguous function overloads are poorly documented. Do not create ambiguous function overloads. As for why they don't work the way you want: because "don't create ambiguous function overloads." Even if it happened to work the way you think it should (in a generic context, what seems obvious is not obvious at all), it's highly ambiguous. Don't do that to the next person who needs to read this code. (Also agreed that the shorter signature is "closer," and therefore selected. The rules are kept simple so that the compiler can be faster.)

Comment: BTW, if it worked the way you're suggesting (considering an unused return value to implicitly be Void for method selection purposes, but not *forced* to be Void for complication purposes), then adding the `@discardableResult` attribute which is documented to only suppress a warning would instead have semantic impact on which method might be selected (and if it didn't have semantic impact, it would be even more bizarre).

Comment: I suspect that this is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74013800/providing-both-an-async-protocol-and-a-completion-block-based-protocol). Don't do these things. Just pick either the completion handler approach or the async approach.

Comment: @Sweeper would be interested to know the answer to "how can I get it to call the void-returning overload". But interesting that it chooses the one with least params.

Comment: @Paulw11 Not related to my other question, sorry

Comment: Makes sense. The functions kind of do the same things which is why I wanted to keep the names the same, except one has a completion handler and another returns a Combine publisher.